# merge textbox values with javascript by element type

Tags: javascript

I have 3 textboxs.Their names and ids are different.I can merge their values with their names or ids but I need to merge their values with type. How can I do it.

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="textbox1">
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="textbox2">
<input type="text" id="txt3" name="textbox3">
```

Comment: ehhhhhh.... what is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please explain what you are expecting as result of the *merge*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the textbox elements by their type using `document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")`. 
If by merge you mean concatenating the values.

```
var textBoxes= document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
var mergedValue;

for(var i=0;i<textBoxes.length;i++)
{
   mergedValue+=textBoxes[i].value;
}
```

Comment: THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution.

```js
function mergeData() {
  var textboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var mergedText = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++) {
    if (textboxes[i].type === "text" ) {
      mergedText = mergedText + textboxes[i].value;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("merged").innerHTML = mergedText;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="textbox1">
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="textbox2">
<input type="text" id="txt3" name="textbox3">
<button onclick="mergeData()">Merge</button>

<div  id="merged"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dataVal=document.querySelectorAll('[type=text]');
var myVal="";
dataVal.forEach(function(entry) {
    myVal+=entry.value;
});

console.log(myVal);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="textbox1" value="2">
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="textbox2" value="2">
<input type="text" id="txt3" name="textbox3" value="2">
```